# Conflicto SETTER , VOLLEY ANDROID

Tags: java, android, jackson, volley

Actualmente estoy trabajando con VOLLEY , en android studio , tengo el siguiente metodo

```
String rq = RequestManager.login(numeroTelefonico,pass);


         GenericController gC = new GenericController();
         gC.login(Login.this, rq, new Response.Listener<LoginMapeador>() {
             @Override
             public void onResponse(LoginMapeador response) {

                 LoginMapeador auxx = response ;
                 progressDialog.dismiss();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
             }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
             @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                 Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error con el servidor,Comuniquese con el soporte  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 progressDialog.dismiss();
             }
        });
```

El cual a al hora de probar el RQ generado por medio de POSTMAN , si recibo una respuesta correcta , y tengo otros servicios utilizando la misma metodologia y estan andando , pero aqui este me tira error en android.context.ContextWrapper , y me dice algo de

```
Conflicting setter definitions for property "wallpaper"
```

la clase que me muestra que tengo mal es la de ObjetRequest

```
 public class ObjetRequest<T> extends JsonRequest<T> {
 JsonRequest<T> {
     @JsonIgnore
     private final Class<T> clazz;
     @JsonIgnore
     private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     @JsonIgnore
     private String myCookie;
     @JsonIgnore
     private static final String MSG = "Error en respuesta";

     /**
      * Creates a new request.
      *
      * @param method        the HTTP method to use
      * @param url           URL to fetch the JSON from
      * @param request       A {@link String} to post with the request. Null is allowed and
      *                      indicates no parameters will be posted along with request.
      * @param listener      Listener to receive the JSON response
      * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
      */
     public ObjetRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> clazz, String request, Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
         super(method, url, request, listener, errorListener);
         this.clazz = clazz;
     }

     @Override
     protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
         try {
            if (this.getMyCookie() == null || this.getMyCookie().equals("")) {
                 this.setMyCookie(response.headers.get("Set-Cookie"));
             }

             String json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            T tmp = mapper.readValue(json, clazz); // ACA MARCA EL LOG
             return Response.success(tmp, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
         } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
             Log.e("Net", MSG, e);
             return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
         } catch (JsonParseException e) {
             Log.e("Net", MSG, e);
             return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
         } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            Log.e("Net", MSG, e);
             return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
         } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.e("Net", MSG, e);
             return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
         }
     }

     public String getMyCookie() {
         return myCookie;
     }
      public void setMyCookie(String myCookie) {
         this.myCookie = myCookie;
     } }`
```

> 12-18 11:01:40.115 17602-17881/com.myapp.test.bimo E/Net: Error en respuesta
>                                                                       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "wallpaper": android.content.ContextWrapper#setWallpaper(1 params) vs android.content.ContextWrapper#setWallpaper(1 params)
>                                                                        at [Source: {"headerRS":{"orgMsgId":"MMJSON","orgChannelRef":"ChannelReference","orgChannelId":"BIMOAPP","orgTransactionType":"LOGIN.LG-M-OL-S","timestamp":"2017-12-18T11:01:39-03:00","errorCode":"0","errorDesc":""},"messageRS":{"errorCode":"-34444","description":"Login no autorizado","sessionToken":"","needChangePassword":"","needRecoveryInfo":"","DATA":""}}; line: 1, column: 1]
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:268)
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:476)
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:3899)
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3794)
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2842)
>                                                                           at com.myapp.test.volley.ObjetRequest.parseNetworkResponse(ObjetRequest.java:57)
>                                                                           at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:123)
>                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "wallpaper": android.content.ContextWrapper#setWallpaper(1 params) vs android.content.ContextWrapper#setWallpaper(1 params)
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getSetter(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:319)
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.filterBeanProps(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:602)
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.addBeanProps(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:497)
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:226)
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:141)
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:403)
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244) 
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142) 
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:476) 
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:3899) 
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3794) 
>                                                                           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2842) 
>                                                                           at com.myapp.test.volley.ObjetRequest.parseNetworkResponse(ObjetRequest.java:57) 
>                                                                           at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:123) 
>   12-18 11:01:40.155 17602-17602/com.myapp.test.bimo D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null

Agrego las clases para mapear la respuesta

```
    public class LoginMapeador {
    @JsonIgnore
    private HeaderRS headerRS ;
    @JsonIgnore
    private LoginRS messageRS;

    public LoginMapeador(){
        this.headerRS = new HeaderRS();
        this.messageRS = new LoginRS();
    }

    public HeaderRS getHeaderRS() {
        return headerRS;
    }

    public void setHeaderRS(HeaderRS headerRS) {
        this.headerRS = headerRS;
    }

    public LoginRS getMessageRS() {
        return messageRS;
    }

    public void setMessageRS(LoginRS messageRS) {
        this.messageRS = messageRS;
    }
}
```

Clase HeaderRS

```
 public class HeaderRS {
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty("orgMsgId")
    private String orgMsgId;
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty("orgChannelRef")
    private String orgChannelRef;
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty("orgChannelId")
    private String orgChannelId;
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty("orgTransactionType")
    private String orgTransactionType;
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty("errorCode")
    private String errorCode;
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty("errorDesc")
    private String errorDesc;
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty("timestamp")
    private String timestamp;

    public HeaderRS(){

    }

    public HeaderRS(String orgMsgId, String orgChannelRef, String orgChannelId, String orgTransactionType, String errorCode, String errorDesc,String timestamp) {
        this.orgMsgId = orgMsgId;
        this.orgChannelRef = orgChannelRef;
        this.orgChannelId = orgChannelId;
        this.orgTransactionType = orgTransactionType;
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorDesc = errorDesc;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getOrgMsgId() {
        return orgMsgId;
    }

    public void setOrgMsgId(String orgMsgId) {
        this.orgMsgId = orgMsgId;
    }

    public String getOrgChannelRef() {
        return orgChannelRef;
    }

    public void setOrgChannelRef(String orgChannelRef) {
        this.orgChannelRef = orgChannelRef;
    }

    public String getOrgChannelId() {
        return orgChannelId;
    }

    public void setOrgChannelId(String orgChannelId) {
        this.orgChannelId = orgChannelId;
    }

    public String getOrgTransactionType() {
        return orgTransactionType;
    }

    public void setOrgTransactionType(String orgTransactionType) {
        this.orgTransactionType = orgTransactionType;
    }

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public String getErrorDesc() {
        return errorDesc;
    }

    public void setErrorDesc(String errorDesc) {
        this.errorDesc = errorDesc;
    }
}
```

Clase MessageRS

```
 public class LoginRS {
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty("errorCode")
    private String errorCode;
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String description;
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty("sessionToken")
    private String sessionToken;
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty("DATA")
    private String DATA;
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty("needChangePassword")
    private String needChangePassword;
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty("needRecoveryInfo")
    private String needRecoveryInfo;

    public LoginRS (){

    }

    public LoginRS(String errorCode, String description, String sessionToken, String DATA, String needChangePassword, String needRecoveryInfo) {
        this();
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.description = description;
        this.sessionToken = sessionToken;
        this.DATA = DATA;
        this.needChangePassword = needChangePassword;
        this.needRecoveryInfo = needRecoveryInfo;
    }

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getSessionToken() {
        return sessionToken;
    }

    public void setSessionToken(String sessionToken) {
        this.sessionToken = sessionToken;
    }

    public String getDATA() {
        return DATA;
    }

    public void setDATA(String DATA) {
        this.DATA = DATA;
    }

    public String getNeedChangePassword() {
        return needChangePassword;
    }

    public void setNeedChangePassword(String needChangePassword) {
        this.needChangePassword = needChangePassword;
    }

    public String getNeedRecoveryInfo() {
        return needRecoveryInfo;
    }

    public void setNeedRecoveryInfo(String needRecoveryInfo) {
        this.needRecoveryInfo = needRecoveryInfo;
    }
}
```

El RS que me llega es este 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busqueda del metodo en todo el proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para Inicializar el ObjetRequest tengo una clase GenericControleer que en el consutrctor hace

```
  public GenericController() {

    objectRequest = new ObjetRequest<>(1, "", BaseRequest.class, "", new Response.Listener<BaseRequest>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(BaseRequest response) {

            // response
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Error
        }
    });
}
```

, debo tener unos 20 servicios andando con esta misma extructura pero no quiere andar con este , el generic controller , lo doy de alta aqui

```
  GenericController gC = new GenericController();
        gC.login(Login.this, rq, new Response.Listener<LoginMapeador>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(LoginMapeador response) {

                LoginMapeador auxx = response ;
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error con el servidor,Comuniquese con el soporte  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Comment: El problema al perecer está en la clase POJO a la cual quieres mapear la respuesta, dice que tiene dos método `setWallpaper`. ¿Por qué no muestras el código de dicha clase?

Comment: Las clases que utilizo para mapear el json ?

Comment: si, pon la clase  que viene en  "clazz" , completa

Comment: Agrege todas las clase que utilizo

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes todo anotado con `@JsonIgnore`. Esa anotación es para propiedades que no existan en el JSON de respuesta. O sea, si en el POJO hay alguna propiedad que no esté en el JSON debe tener esa anotación, pero yo veo que tienes todo anotado para ser ignorado, ¿por qué?

Comment: tienes algun método o atributo llamado 'wallpaper'

Comment: No tengo ningun metodo llamado WallPaper , y puse JsonIgnore a todo porque estaba probando haber si podia ser algo de eso ! ese wallpaper lo encontre en la clase android.context. ContextWrapper , pero esta clase es de Java y no me la deja tocar , no entiendo

Comment: Quita `@JsonIgnore`  a todas las propiedades que existan en la respuesta JSON.

Comment: Si ya las quite , aunque el problema no va por eso , porque me tira el mismo error

Comment: busca el método  : setWallpaper en todo tu proyecto

Comment: como dije solo aparece ese metodo en Context.class

Comment: edite y deje imagen arriba

Comment: como inicializas esto : ObjetRequest , puedes poner ese código cuando lo llamas

Comment: te lo deje en comentarios

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás tratando de parsear el JSON a una clase incorrecta, en lugar de esto:

```
 objectRequest = new ObjetRequest<>(1, "", BaseRequest.class, "", new Response.Listener<BaseRequest>() {
```

Deberías usar esto:

```
 objectRequest = new ObjetRequest<>(1, "", LoginMapeador.class, "", new Response.Listener< LoginMapeador >() {
```

Comment: En si tienes razon , aunque yo este metodo , lo reutilizo pero en un metodo que no llege a mostrar aqui , tenia mal seteado justamente esto , por lo que muchas gracias , nose porque alguien te voto negativo , yo te di positivo y repsuesta aceptada gracias